# Is the set $(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3; xy + yz + zx \leq 1$ compact?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

As in the title, I am stuck in proving whether that set is compact or not. If I were in two dimensions I could perhaps manage to rewrite it in some manner, but in this way I cannot hink of much.

$$xy + xz + yz \leq 1 \rightarrow 2xy + 2yz + 2zx \leq 2 \rightarrow (x+y+z)^2 - (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \leq 2$$

But at this point I'm like stuck.

I feel like the set is not bounded. If $x = -y = -z$ I could ge a large negative number, large as I like. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. The set is not bounded, as you showed, and compacts are bounded.

Comment: @mihaild Thank you!!

Comment: It is the part of the 3D space containing the origin  which is delimited by a hyperboloid with 2 sheets https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+xy%2Byz%2Bzx%3D1 "visibly" unbounded.

Comment: also $(0,0,z)  $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct, let's write a rigorous proof for the unboundedness. Recall that a set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is bounded if there exists a ball with radius $R>0$ centered in $(0,0,0)$ that contains $A$.

The point you chose is $(-z,z,z)$, which belongs to your set if and only if $(-z)z+zz+z(-z)\le 1\iff-z^2 \le 1$, that is for each $z\in\mathbb{R}$. Since it is$\|(-z,z,z)\|=\sqrt{3}|z|$, given an arbitrary $M>0$ it is:
$$\|(-z,z,z)\|>M\iff\sqrt{3}|z|>M\iff(z>M/\sqrt{3})\ \lor \ (z<-M/\sqrt{3})$$

Since we can take any arbitrary $z\in\mathbb{R}$, at least one of the inequalities $(z>M/\sqrt{3})\ \lor \ (z<-M/\sqrt{3})$ can always be satisfied and so no ball contains your set. Hence, your set is unbounded.

Comment: Wow, awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Can I think of that number $M$ as if it were the radius $R$ of the ball?

Comment: Yes. I used $M$ to avoid confusion with the other $R$ of the general definition I gave.